# prepending an anonymous type to an Enumerable<TSource>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, c#-4.0

I have the below code example where I want to [prepend](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Prepend.cs) some text on to the front of the source param which could be of type `ISite` or `IFactory` used in a MVC drop down list via a [MoreLinq extension](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Prepend.cs). This function is used in a controller action that returns the list serialised as JSON so that it can be loaded dynamically using some dropdown cascading, otherwise I would have done this separately in a view model.

I was wondering if there is a way to be able to do something similar to the below without having to create a concrete ListItem class, my example shows how I am using `as IListItem` but I am aware this won't compile.

At the moment my controller has no concept of any of my model's concrete classes and I kind of wanted to keep it that way and I'm not sure if I definately need to make an instance of a ListItem to make this work or if anyone has another suggestion?

My knowledge of Covariance and Contravariance in Generics is limited, in case that is of importance here? Thanks

```
    public interface IListItem
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
        string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public interface ISite : IListItem
    {
        int CountryId { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IFactory : IListItem
    {
        int SiteId { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IResource
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
        string Name { get; set; }
        int ContentID { get; set; }
        string Text { get; set; }
        int LanguageID { get; set; }
        string LanguageCode { get; set; }
        int Priority { get; set; }
    }

private IEnumerable<IListItem> PrependSelectionResource(IEnumerable<IListItem> source, string languageCode)
{
    if(source == null || source.Count() == 1)
        return source; // don't bother prepending the relevant resource in these cases

    try
    {
        // will throw an exception if languageCode is null or blank
        var resource = _resourceRepository.GetByNameAndLanguageCode(
            "Prompt_PleaseSelect",
            languageCode);

        if(resource == null)
            return source;

        // prepend the "Please Select" resource to the beginning of the source
        // using MoreLinq extension
        return source.Prepend(new {
            Id = 0,
            Name = resource.Text ?? ""
        } as IListItem);
    }
    catch {
        return source;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's nothing you can do. You'll have to pass a concrete instance of a class that implements the `IListItem` interface to the `Prepend` method.

If you're worried about exposing implementations elsewhere in your application, you could create a local implementation to your file called `PlaceholderListItem` and use that instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That says to me then that I might benefit from having my `_resourceRepository` be able to return a resource as a `IListItem` maybe? only its a bit out of place because I only really need the `resource.Text` and the Id I would prefer to be "" but its likely needs to be 0.. rather than the resource's record ID

Answer (score 2):

An anonymous type (like `new { Id = 0, Name = resource.Text ?? "" }`) is a class that does not implement any interfaces (and has no other base classes than `object`). So it won't work.

If you use a mocking framework, you can create a *mock* that is some magically generated class which implements the interface. Sometimes also called a *stub*.

But in this case, it's really easy to write your own mock, of course:

```
class ListItemMock : IListItem
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

then you can instantiate it with an object initializer: `new ListItemMock { Id = 0, Name = resource.Text ?? "", }`.